# Leaflet Sidebar-V2 Width CSS

Tags: css, leaflet, width, sidebar, pane

I'm trying to increase the width of the pane section of [Sidebar-V2](https://github.com/turbo87/sidebar-v2/) on a leafletJS map, preferably by twice, or to half the map container's width.

[image: current state]

At the moment the content doesn't fit and is constrained by the pane width, I'm unsure as to how to make it wider.

I've tried tweaking several values in the CSS file but to no avail. The CSS can be found [here](https://github.com/noerw/leaflet-sidebar-v2)

There is a solution for version 1 which can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248036/has-anyone-figured-out-how-to-make-leaflet-sidebar-v1-wider).

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Everything can be changed in the leaflet-sidebar.css file, just open the devTool console, e.g. in chrome [sidebar-v2](https://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/examples/index.html)

Comment: Perfect, found exactly what i needed, thank you for the direction.